# Nested routes not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am creating an API with rails5.beta, I followed the guide to create nested routes: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

My Models:

```
class Paymethod < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :transactions
end

class Transaction < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :paymethod
end
```

and routes.rb

```
resources :paymethods do
    resources :transactions
end
```

`rake routes` gives me:

```
 paymethod_transactions GET    /paymethods/:paymethod_id/transactions(.:format)     transactions#index
```

But I always getting same output for any `paymethod_id`

`GET aymethods/1/transactions`

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "amount": 10,
    "user_id": 21,
    "paymethod_id": 1,
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "amount": 1,
    "user_id": 21,
    "paymethod_id": 1,
  }
]
```

and same by: `GET paymethods/2/transactions`

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "amount": 10,
    "user_id": 21,
    "paymethod_id": 1,
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "amount": 1,
    "user_id": 21,
    "paymethod_id": 1,
  }
]
```

So, why its not filtering the results by `paymethod_id`?

Btw, it works with rails like `Paymethod.find(2).transactions`

Here a controllers:
https://gist.github.com/nilsigusi/f59e65dd34495e08eaee

actually its standard controllers, generated by creating a model with rails

Comment: Can  you show what your controller looks like?

Comment: Your controller probably does not find the proper Paymethod. Like KyleDecot said, we need to see your controller to check if you do `Paymethod.find(params[:paymethod_id]).transactions`

Comment: I updated question with controllers.

Comment: I did not modify controllers, because it was not mentioned in tutorial. Should I do this?

Comment: Maybe later in the tutorial they tell you about this flaw/error in the code. But sure thing is that doing `Transaction.all` is not what you want here, you want transactions of a specific paymethod, in rails code `Paymethod.find(params[:paymethod_id]).transactions`

Comment: doing `Paymethod.find(params[:paymethod_id]).transactions` works, but then I would give up a normal route for `GET transactions`.  Could I do both?

Comment: Actually according to your routes, you can't hit `GET /transactions` but only `GET /paymethods/:paymethod_id/transactions`, so you will always have a `params[:paymethod_id]`

Comment: thank you.. I am having the understanding now, how it supposed to work! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your gist, you had this at line 59: ( https://gist.github.com/nilsigusi/f59e65dd34495e08eaee#file-gistfile1-txt-L59 )

```
@transactions = Transaction.all
```

Which return all transaction records, no condition applied.

Replace with this:

```
@transactions = Transaction.where(paymethod_id: params[:paymethod_id])
```

To get all the transaction records belonging to the paymethod.

Comment: Why is this not in the documentation? I read the documentation and it makes it sounds like nested routing works automatically.